# Fortify - Value never read foreach loop

Tags: java, fortify

Fortify scan on my code throws me the error

```
The method getData() in Utils.java never uses the value it assigns to the variable fooBar on line 373.
```

The code at the mentioned line is simple

```
for (FooBar fooBar : fooBarList) // this is my line #373
{
somedata.put(fooBar.getFoo(), fooBar.getBar());
}
```

It is just an iteration over the list and I am using the variable. So what seems wrong here? Is this an issue with Fortify or am I missing some standard way to write such loops?

Comment: You may want to have a [tag:java] tag?

Comment: Do you ever read from `somedata` ?

Comment: Is method getData() ever used?

Comment: @Marit My guess is, that this for loop is in `getData()`...

Comment: @Marit : the loop is in the method getData()

Comment: @diginoise : yes, I do read someData and Fortify only complains about the variable fooBar.

Comment: is this exact source of `getData()`. Fortify tells you that you are assigning something to `fooBar` then never use it and assign to it something else. 
The first assignment is in for loop, but maybe you assign something else to it between `for` and `somedara.put()` lines. Can you please highlight line# 373?

Comment: @diginoise: That is all the code I have in the loop. Just one line.